# Searching an Ember.js content array for a specific value

Tags: ember.js

In my app I'm taking a search term from an input field and stuffing it into an array:

```
guitar
bass
drums
```

When a new term is entered, I'd first like to check if it already exists in the array. Then, if it does, I'd like to extract it from it's current position and move it to the top of the stack. I believe I've got a handle on that last part using .unshiftObject(). I just wonder if there's an Ember way of searching through the array.

**update** answering my own question

```
App.recentUsersArray = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    addUser: function(name) {
        console.log(this.get('content').contains(name));
        this.pushObject(name);
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahhh...the contains method is just the trick. Amazing what you can learn when you read the source. Updating question and including the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a combination of `removeObject` and `unshiftObject`, see http://jsfiddle.net/a3xLb/

```
App.recentUsersArray = Em.ArrayProxy.create({
    addAndMoveUserToFront: function(username) {
        this.removeObject(username);
        this.unshiftObject(username);
    }
});​
```

Comment: Clemens...I actually tried using unshiftObject but it didn't work.

Comment: I did, and yes yours works. I think I see what I was doing wrong. I think I tried getting the content array first and applying the change to it, rather than to "this" like you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

By using ember, you're using jQuery. So you can use `jQuery.inArray()`

```
position = jQuery.inArray(name, this.get('content'));
if (position != -1) {
  # The element is in the array
  this.get('content').slice(position, 1);
}
this.get('content').pushObject(name)
```